# Cant put multiple images in one tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
nameList = ["images/icons/first.bmp", "images/icons/second.bmp"]
ycord = 0
for execute in nameList:
    myimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(execute))
    Label(image=myimg).place(x=0, y=0)
    ycord += 80

root.mainloop()
```

With this code, for some reason the `first.bmp` doesnt get shown in the tkinter window. Only the `second.bmp` does appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: (Not exactly the same situation, but it's the same root cause.)

Comment: Not sure if it does answer my question. Answers suggest using `global` ( i dont have a def here) or use `self.` which i dont have a class.

Comment: It is because you use same variable `myimg` to store the references of images, so only the last image is being referenced and those other images are garbage collected.  One of the way is use an attribute of the label to store the reference of the image.

Comment: I really do get the logic of what you are saying here but I still cant see a way. Still trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you use same variable `myimg` to store the references of images, so only the last image is being referenced and those other images are garbage collected. One of the way is use an attribute of the label to store the reference of the image.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
nameList = ["images/icons/first.bmp", "images/icons/second.bmp"]
ycord = 0
for execute in nameList:
    myimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=execute)
    lbl = Label(root, image=myimg)
    lbl.place(x=0, y=ycord)
    lbl.image = myimg  # use an attribute of label to store the reference of image
    ycord += 80

root.mainloop()
```